# Downloading CentOS 7.2 64-bit (or CentOS 6.8, 64 bit)?

Tags: centos-7, centos-6

For some reason (software compatibility with RedHawk), I need to use CentOS 7.2 (64-bit) instead of the most updated version of CentOS 7.6.1810. I am asking around to see if there is still a chance for me to get CentOS 7.2 (7.2.1511)?

Similarly, could CentOS 6.8 be still available for download instead of 6.10?

Thanks for everybody's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find older/archived versions on the downloads page of the CentOS site.
Here you go: https://wiki.centos.org/Download
All the older versions are listed, 7, 6, 5, back to 2.1